# Preferred blade/tool for 'Rip cuts' on LVP?

Tags: cutting, vinyl

So I have a LOT of rips to make in this floor, installing 6 x 48" Durato "Luxury Vinyl Planking". The customer now wants it glued (separate issue). He also insists on keeping his new(ish) 4" deco base in place. Also insists no quarter round be used. I guess I have always hid behind those options when installing vinyl. Does anyone have a favorite tool or method for ripping Vinyl? Favorite type skill saw blade? I am planning on using the guide arm for my 5 1/4" or 7 1/4" Skills (if I can find them lol) but...should I go with a finish blade or something even finer? My grinder chews into it, the framing blades chew into it....I'll have no cover for these cuts. Thanks in advance! I am happy to completely change my game-plan based on some good advice.

Comment: I hope you are charging more for following the wishes of the client. it is possible they are try to save money by not needing to repair the base. The ONLY way I would install the floor is by pulling the base AND not use shoe. Whether it is floating or glued. A table saw is my choice of ripping a lot of flooring....very far away from the work area. Getting any "dust" from the ripping process under the floor will be disastrous.

Comment: You might doublecheck with the manufacturer to see that they don't need expansion gaps... it could be your way out of the baseboard problem.

Comment: Please get paid up front for this job...

Comment: thanks guys. Yeah this is going to need a hefty deposit...lol. I am going to meet with both he and the flooring supplier and get everyone on the same page before I even touch this.

Comment: use cheap blades; the extremely hard coating on some flooring really dulls them anyway.